# Select the row in a listbox when button in it is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm assuming this is a simple thing that I am missing.

I have a `ListBox` in a WPF app that I am writing.  Each row has a button to perform a simple action based on the row that the button is on.  If the user clicks on the button directly then the `SelectedItem` on the `ListBox` is null.  If I click in the row first, then click the button the `SelectedItem` is the row, as expected.

I want to be able to have the row that the button is on selected when the button is clicked.  Again, I'm assuming that I am missing something simple, but my searches are coming up empty so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to select `ListBoxItem` on button click of ListBoxItem you can do this by attaching click handler to your button.

Assuming you have this XAML for ListBox declaration:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Button Content="{Binding PropertyName}" Click="Button_Click"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

you can select listBoxItem from handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.
                               ContainerFromItem(((Button)sender).DataContext);
    selectedItem.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Access `DataContext` of button which will be same as that of ListBoxItem. Hence, with it you can get container element i.e. ListBoxItem from `ItemContainerGenerator`.

Set `IsSelected` to `True` on fetched listBoxItem.